# How should this be done? (returing a collection of values)

Tags: c#, php, weather-api

I am writing a weather API to connect to the NOAA's XML METARS in C# NETMF. Before, this API was written in PHP, where I was able to use an associative array to return the weather parameters. For example, the return of the `getWX()` function might have been

```
Array(
"temp_f" => "70.0",
"windchil" => "65.0",
"wind_dir" => "90"
);
```

I am trying to replicate that same functionality in my CSharp version, but I am not sure how to go about doing it. Since I am using NETMF, I cannot use a hashtable.

Should I use a struct instead?

In case anyone wants to see the code behind the original PHP API, it is here: http://www.chrisseto.com/wordpress/?p=17
I am trying to get the CSharp version to be as similar as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, if I'm reading the documentation correctly (and I'd like to think I am), [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff689103%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx) class is very much available in 4.1

Comment: My platform is, and will be 4.0 for some months. The OEM has to update the runtime, so I am at their mercy.

Comment: Never used NETMF, but does it not contain collections (in 4.0)? Dictionary<string,string> for example?

Comment: Yeah! It does seem to have a dictionary collection in 4.0! Would that be appropriate for me to use for such a project?

Comment: I do not see why you can not use the dictionary. A dictionary is practically a strong typed Hashtable.